# How to display nested Json on pie chart?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have this JSon on localhost.

```
{
    "sucess": true,
    "total":150,
    "casa": [{
        "name": {
            "mentor": "stark"
            },
        "data":60
    },{
        "name":"baratheon",
        "data":50
    },{
        "name":"lannister",
        "data":40
    },{
        "name":"baratheon",
        "data":30
    },{
        "name":"greyjoy",
        "data":20
    },{
        "name":"tyrell",
        "data":10 
    }]
 }
```

And this Js.

```
Ext.onReady(function() { 

    Ext.define('User', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields: [ {
                    name: 'name',
                    type: 'string'
                }, {
                    name: 'data',
                    type: 'int'
                }]
            });

            var store= Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    storeId: 'casas',
                    model: 'User',
                    autoLoad: true,
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: 'lala1.json',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'casa'
                        }
                    }
                });

       Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
            renderTo: 'myExample',
            width: 450,
            height: 320,
            legend: {
                position: 'right'
            },
            animate: true,
            store: store,
            theme: 'Base:gradients',
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                angleField: 'data',

                showInLegend: true,
                tips: {
                    trackMouse: true,
                    width: 140,
                    height: 28,

                    renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                        var total = 0;
                        store.each(function(rec) {
                            total += rec.get('data');
                        });
                        this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' +     Math.round(storeItem.get('data') / total * 100) + '%');
                    }
                },
                highlight: {
                    segment: {
                        margin: 20
                    }
                },
                label: {
                    field: 'name',
                    display: 'rotate',
                    contrast: true,
                    font: '18px Arial'
                }
            }]
        });
     });
```

And every time I try to display the mentor's name, just displays [object Object] on the field on pie chart. I missed something? I've already read some posts here about this but none of them fixed my problem, someone can help me?

Comment: What do you want to display as title when name contains object with mentors name? Just mentors name?

Comment: Yes, the mentors name. And now my only result is [object Object] on the field.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your json, change its structure to look like extjs expects it:

```
"name": "stark",
"data":60
```

instead of

```
"name": {
    "mentor": "stark"
},
"data":60
```

If your json originates from a third party source, you have to transform your data before drawing the chart. A way of achieving this would be to transform the data using the store's [`load` event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-load), which gets the records as a parameter.

Comment: THis Json is just an example what a I have to do, and this Json will come to me nested like this and I'm trying to get the value, on this case mentor, to display on my pie chart, but just displaying '[object Object]

Comment: So this json comes from a third party source ?